# Capturar id do datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

Se eu quero capturar o valor da coluna ID da linha selecionada, eu preciso necessariamente usar o vento `SelectionChanged`, que é para ser disparado a cada troca de linha no datagrid? Ou só com o `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value`, eu ja consigo isso?

Esse é meu método, caso queiram entender o contexto:

```
private void EfetuarPedido()
        {
            int id_Posicao_Selecionada = 0;
            int quantidade_Posicao = 0;

            tratarErro.Clear();

            quantidade_Posicao = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPosicoesParaPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
            id_Posicao_Selecionada = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPosicoesParaPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

            if (Convert.ToDouble(txtPedidoCodigo.Text) < 999999999999)
            {
                tratarErro.SetError(txtPedidoCodigo, "Código inválido");
            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtPedidoQuantidade.Text) <= 0)
            {
                tratarErro.SetError(txtPedidoQuantidade, "Quantidade não pode ser nula");
            }
            else if (quantidade_Posicao > (Convert.ToInt32(txtPedidoQuantidade.Text)))
            {
                tratarErro.SetError(txtPedidoQuantidade, "Não há unidades necessárias na posição escolhida");
            }
            else if(Convert.ToDouble(txtPedidoCodigo.Text) > 999999999999)
            {
                validar.Validacao_FazerPedido(Convert.ToDouble(txtPedidoCodigo.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtPedidoQuantidade.Text), id_Posicao_Selecionada, txtReorganizarDescricao.Text); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O evento só seria útil no seu caso se você precisar atualizar outros campos sempre que o usuário efetuar uma troca na linha selecionada, se não for por isso só pegar o id direto da tabela já deve resolver.

Comment: Ah obrigado, no caso, não vai atualizar nenhum campo, esse método eu vou atribuir ao evento click de um botão, então não tem como ele selecionar outra linha depois de disparar o evento click, obrigado por ter me esclarecido essa dúvida. Eu tava achando que funcionava só com o Evento manja, tipo os valores em pixels dos Axis X e Y dos Chart que só funciona no Evento Paint